# In generalization bound for a single hypothesis, what is the probability with respect to?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, generalization-error

In these notes: https://mostafa-samir.github.io/ml-theory-pt2/ the author writes:

[image]

Here $R(h)$ is the true error/generalization error, and $R_{emp}(h)$ is the empirical risk.

What exactly is the probability $\mathbb{P}$ with respect to? Is it $h$ or the data $x$? Or the dataset $\mathcal{D}$?